# VideoJS: Excessive main segment downloading detected errors during a live event

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, video.js, live-streaming, http-streaming

Our customers encountered `Excessive main segment downloading detected` errors during a large live event, several users saw these errors within a 15 min period during a 2 hour long event. We have looked at the upstream CDN and the packaging service and didn't see any errors. Here are relevant logs collected for a single user.

```
2023-11-07T09:32:29.284-08:00   qualitylevels onchange  {"resolution":360,"mode":0}
2023-11-07T09:32:32.496-08:00   player onwaiting
2023-11-07T09:32:34.740-08:00   VIDEOJS:,WARN:,Problem encountered with playlist 2-index_133.m3u8. Excessive main segment downloading detected. Switching to playlist 1-index_132.m3u8.
2023-11-07T09:32:34.740-08:00   qualitylevels onchange  {"resolution":720,"mode":0}
2023-11-07T09:32:38.727-08:00   VIDEOJS:,WARN:,Problem encountered with playlist 1-index_132.m3u8. Excessive main segment downloading detected. Switching to playlist 0-index_131.m3u8.
2023-11-07T09:32:42.764-08:00   qualitylevels onchange  {"resolution":1080,"mode":0}
2023-11-07T09:32:44.564-08:00   VIDEOJS:,ERROR:,(CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE),Playback cannot continue. No available working or supported playlists.
2023-11-07T09:32:44.564-08:00   player onerror
2023-11-07T09:32:54.015-08:00   VIDEOJS:,ERROR:,(CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE),Playback cannot continue. No available working or supported playlists.
2023-11-07T09:32:56.775-08:00   player onerror
2023-11-07T09:32:58.694-08:00   player onpause
2023-11-07T09:33:02.814-08:00   player onplay
2023-11-07T09:33:04.627-08:00   VIDEOJS:,ERROR:,(CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE),Playback cannot continue. No available working or supported playlists.
2023-11-07T09:36:33.091-08:00       
2023-11-07T09:36:33.091-08:00   / (page refresh)
```

We found few [references](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/8452) of same error on VideoJS issues page, which indicate a fullscreen toggle can cause this issue. I believe in that case the errors to be spread across the event and not just be in 15 min period.

Are there any other reasons that can cause the errors?

Player version: 7.20.3